# Maven pulling in dependency that is not specified in POM

Tags: java, maven, h2

I have a maven project consisting of a parent POM and several sub-modules. It compiles and runs fine within Intellij (I'm assuming this uses `javac` and not Maven).

When I run `maven clean install`, the build fails because of "RequireUpperBoundDeps", which from [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireUpperBoundDeps.html) means a version resolved during the build is lower than a dependency's version for the same artifact. Here is the (sanitized) output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-maven) @ my-service ---
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireUpperBoundDeps failed with message:
Failed while enforcing RequireUpperBoundDeps. The error(s) are [
Require upper bound dependencies error for com.h2database:h2:1.3.168 paths to dependency are:
+-com.example.services:my-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.h2database:h2:1.3.168
and
+-com.example.services:my-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.example.libs:my-libs:2.0.0
    +-com.h2database:h2:1.3.168 (managed) <-- com.h2database:h2:1.4.190
]
```

This seems to be implying that `h2` is a direct dependency of `my-service`, but it is not declared as such in any poms, module or parent. `h2` should only be coming from `my-libs`. Furthermore, it claims that `h2` is "managed" to be version `1.3.168`. I have no idea where it's getting this information. `my-libs` uses `h2` version `1.4.190`.

I've tried starting with a totally fresh `.m2` directory, excluding `h2` from the `my-libs` dependency, explicitly including `h2` under `my-service` (both versions). Nothing works, and excluding `h2` from the dependency results in a `NoSuchPropertyException` on one of my classes that interact with the database (via JDBI).

How can I get maven to recognize the correct version of `h2` to include and to successfully build my project?

Comment: Did you try print the maven dependency tree for your project?

Comment: Yes. `mvn dependency:tree` shows `h2` as a direct dependency of `my-service` even though it is not declared in the pom.

Comment: It shows that h2 is a dependency of my-libs which is a dependency of my-service. The h2 is called a transitve dependency. So you need to take a look into my-libs pom file. This shows that you in my-service declared h2 with version 1.3.168 whereas it is declarad with 1.4.190 which is the cause of the enforcer-rule.... You should check my-libs first and it's parents...search for dependencyManagement....

Comment: @khmarbaise that's what I thought as well. However, `h2` is *not* declared in the `my-service` pom. It *should* only be a transitive dependency, but in fact it is also a direct dependency.

Comment: As i wrote. Check the parent and dependencyManagement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that the `h2` dependency was being pulled in from the parent pom (the parent of `my-service`). `mvn dependency:tree` was deceiving as it shows `h2` as a direct dependency to `my-service`, which in my mind meant that it should be declared in the `my-service` pom. It was not delcared in the `my-service` pom - however, it was declared in the parent pom. That is where the conflicting version came from.

Declaring `h2` in the `my-service` pom with a specified version fixed the upper bound dependencies error.

Answer (score 10):

Someone wrote an excellent article [HERE](https://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2016/08/22/how-to-read-maven-enforcer-plugins-requireupperbounddeps-rule-failure-report/) that provides and understanding of what is happening and possible solutions. Here is the summary -

For this deps tree in the error

```
+-com.example.services:my-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.example.libs:my-libs:2.0.0
    +-com.h2database:h2:1.3.168 (managed) <-- com.h2database:h2:1.4.190
```

The `com.example.services:my-service` project has dependency on version `1.3.168` of `com.h2database:h2` artifact. Also, `com.example.libs:my-libs` needs the same artifact but of different version - `1.4.190`.

Declare `com.h2database:h2:1.3.168` in your pom **(Upgrade Scenario)**

NB: This might not be a suitable solution for all projects.

Alternatively, you can exclude `com.h2database:h2:1.4.190` from `com.example.libs:my-libs`. That way, `com.example.libs:my-libs` will end up using and older version in `com.h2database:h2:1.3.168` **(downgrade scenario)**

To do the latter, your pom entry will look like this:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example.libs</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-libs</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion> 
          <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
          <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

It is a decision you have to make based on your project. I usually start by doing some investigations using `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: Clear, quality answer. I ended up using the downgrade scenario

Answer (score 0):

General answer: Just declare missing dependencies in your pom.xml